# how to handle service Restart in android

Tags: android, service, background

Friends!

I am in a real mess. I am new bee in Android services, and I am not getting useful material regarding the android services.

What I need is when I click on button my service starts and it has a method to upload data on live server and display notification.

Now when firstly I press a button it starts my activity and execute the method but next time my service is in running condition and uploading some data. Now again i press the button to send some more data, and put the data into uploading queue and here I am stucked my on-Start method is not being called again so my new data is not being added to the queue. What do i need to do?

Please Help me with some code to achieve this Friends

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Is this just a one-time upload per button click or does the service continuously upload data to the server until a specified event?

Answer (score 0):

Well... You made a service. The service is still running if your activity is finished. That is the reason why onStart isnt triggered any more.

Comment: so how can i trigger it again ?? i don't want my service to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Use bindService if service is already running..

```
  Intent i = new Intent(); 
i.setClassName("com.android.music", "com.android.music.MediaPlaybackService"); 
ServiceConnection conn = new MediaPlayerServiceConnection(); this.bindService(i, conn, 0);





private class MediaPlayerServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection { 
public IMediaPlaybackService mService; public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) { Log.i("MediaPlayerServiceConnection", "Connected! Name: " + name.getClassName()); 
    }
```

Comment: so what method it will call when i again press on the button while service is running?? please explain

Comment: Basically you call .. context.bind service method if service is already running and if not it creates service. .... have a look at the line this.bindService(i, conn, 0);